# Center text in a div img hover caption

Tags: css

Good evening,

I have this blog: http://bloganacastro.com/ where I have below the logo some last posts. It's almost done. I just can't figure out how to center the text exactly in the middle no matter how many characters have in it. For example, this blog: sempreglamour.com.br works exactly as I want. I already tried to copy some CSS from this blog but won't work too.

EDIT:

Print Screen with the difference about these two blogs http://imageshack.com/a/img661/7620/kr6Ov7.png

As you can see, the image from the right have all exactly perfect padding/margin and no matter the size of the text it always fill exactly. In the example from the left, depending on the size of the text it doesn't fill and it's never really centralized.

Comment: Based on readability, it's a very bad idea to use justified text since hyphens are not widely supported. Perhaps you can show a screenshot of what part you're referring to?

Comment: @ChrisBurton I'll take printscreen and edit my question. Just a moment. Thanks til now and sorry for the delay!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got your problem fixed by just adding `position: absolute` on the `<h3>`, so try it out.

```
.caption-text h3 {
    position: absolute;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

```
.caption {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.caption-text h3 {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.caption-text a {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

and the last thing to remove the existing `padding` you've applied on `.caption-text h3`

Now I'm going to tell you that the main thing to vertically align the text in middle was set on `.caption-text a`, you'll see `transfrom` and `top`, those do the vertical centering. Now no matter whatever the length of the text, it will be in center. The `width` and `height` on other elements were necessary so that they expand fully inside the `li` and then the centering can happen easily.

Comment: Hi, Rohit! Thank you so much for your reply. It's almost done, this trick have done something with the letters. If you don't have problem with this, you could explain what this setting do? Also now, the letters are OK, but all the phrase still not centered in frame. Tried some CSS like margin and padding, I can center but depending on how many characters it didn't work properly.

Comment: actually, you have a lot of nested `div` and `li` and `a`, that's all getting me confused and its hard to edit with my code inspector live, it will be much better if you could produce the problem by copying the snippets on jsfiddle.net

Comment: @RodrigoSchneiderWernke you can google for the `position` property, btw I got your problem fully fixed up, check my updated answer.

Comment: Man, thank you so much! Finally I got this! I'll google about all that you've done to understand it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about centering text horizontally, this should do it:

```
.class {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Already tried to put center in all classes or/and divs. I'll put a printscreen at the question.